# MVC Admin reset of User Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc

After a lot of messing around, and with some excellent help from [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson), I got this working.

On my system, when an admin user logs in, a link appears for them to go into the user management system. This provides a list of users, the ability to create another user, delete them, or change their details.

Also, when ANY user logs in they are able to change their own password. However, if a user forgets their password, the admin user must reset the password. I'm not emailing them a link or anything fancy. In the "List Users" bit in the admin screen, there is an Actions column that contains links to edit, delete, show details, and reset password.

I have an ApplicationUsersController that contains the functions to edit, delete, etc. I have a series of ApplicationUsers views called Create, Edit, Delete, Details, Edit, Index. Most of this code was generated when I created an ApplicationUsersController and chose to create the views. There is also a ResetUserPasswordsViewModel as well. Here is the ResetPassword view:

```
@model ICWeb.Models.ResetUserPasswordViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset User Password";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "Please fix the errors displayed", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NewPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.NewPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @autofocus = "autofocus" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NewPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ConfirmPassword, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

In the controller I have:

```
    // GET: /ApplicationUsers/ResetPassword
    public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
    {
        return View(new ResetUserPasswordViewModel() { Id = id });
    }

    //POST: /ApplicationUsers/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetUserPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return View(model);
        }

        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store);
        string userId = model.Id;
        string newPassword = model.NewPassword;
        string hashedNewPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);
        ApplicationUser cUser = await store.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);
        await store.UpdateAsync(cUser);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

After a lot of messing around, I re-did this function. The view loads now and I can type in 2 new passwords. When I submit, the ResetPassword function runs. I can see when I step through the code it has the passwords I typed, and by editing the GET function to populate the model with the Id, I now get the Id of the user. The whole controller access is limited to users with admin permissions, so unless you're an admin you can't do anything here.

In my ResetUserPasswordModel I have:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace ICWeb.Models
{
    public class ResetUserPasswordViewModel
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "New password")]
        public string NewPassword { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm new password")]
        [Compare("NewPassword", ErrorMessage = "The new password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }
}
```

All sorted, and the help was, and is, very much appreciated.

Comment: maybe you need a viewmodel object then which _does_ contain those fields? Also why have you got `id` as a separate parameter? Surely that's part of the model already?

Comment: id was probably a hangover from something I was trying. I have removed it. I have added a ResetUserPasswordViewModel class. It contains an Id property, password and a confirmpassword property

Comment: ok good. So...did it solve your problem?

Comment: No. I changed the view to use the ApplicationUsersModels in the opening line which contains the id, newpassword and confirmpassword properties. The httppost function ResetPassword is clearly just wrong. Any thoughts on what that needs to be? All I want to do is reset a password for a selected user in AspNetUsers. The user administration page lists my users and the Reset Password link is in the form:

ApplicationUsers/ResetPassword/d1b8e05e-07df-4276-95e6-959b6c6a2b99

So the Id is being passed to the Reset Password page.

Comment: the post needs to accept your new viewmodel as the parameter as well. Did you do that? Maybe update your question with the latest code and current issues with it. It's difficult to be sure just based on a description

Comment: I updated the code in the question to what I have now. I can't post it as a comment and I don't seem to be able to do it any other way. The reset password page is loading. It is clear the ResetPassword function in the controller is wrong. Not sure what code to put there really.

Comment: " can't post it as a comment "...no and you absolutely shouldn't do that anyway, so don't worry. The question should contain all the relevant details. Edits to questions are fine. BTW you should have updated the descriptions really, it doesn't make a lot of sense. And what's wrong with the code in your Post which is currently commented out? Does it produce an exception of some sort when you include it? It doesn't look unreasonable. Please clarify (by editing the question). You definitely shouldn't be returning BadRequest at the end though...that's only for validation errors. Just return a view

Comment: Ok, hopefully I'm nearly there. Just not picking up the Id for some reason.

Comment: Well, in `public ActionResult ResetPassword()
    {
        return View();
    }` you return an empty model, so Id will not be populated. And you are putting Id in a hidden field in the view, so there's no opportunity for the user to change it. Therefore it will always be empty. When you make the GET request to the initial resetpassword action, you need to send the ID of the user with it, and the resetpassword method needs to receive it as a parameter, then you put into a model object return that, so it's then placed into the hidden field, ready for posting back with the completed form.

Comment: e.g. it would be something like `public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
    {
        return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel() { Id = id });
    }`

Comment: Oh, yeah! Initial get. I completely forgot that! You are right. I have just tested with your suggestion rather than pulling from RouteData and it worked perfectly! Should I update the code in my question? How do you accept answers on here?

Comment: well I've only written comments, not answers. You accept _answers_ by clicking on the tick next to it to make it go green, but i haven't written one, because it was more of a gradual debugging exercise with several steps than a one-stop answer.

Answer (score 0):

In the system I'm developing (but not yet completed or tested) I've got this written. It works so should be a good starting point. Note that the view model takes care of mis-match passwords so that is covered for you already.

I use Direct Injection for the User Manager - just replace my _userManager with your own instance,  however you create it.

```
@model Models.ResetPasswordViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Reset password";
}

<div class="container">
    @if (ViewBag.Error != null)
    {
        <div class="alert-danger mb-2">Error(s) occured : @ViewBag.Error</div>
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "AllUsers", null, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })
    }
    else
    {
        using (Html.BeginForm("ResetPassword", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" })

            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(model => model.UserName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control", @readonly = "" } })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "control-label" })
                @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>

            <div class="form-group d-flex">
                @Html.ActionLink("Back to User Edit", "EditUser", "Account", new { userId = Model.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary" })

                <input type="submit" value="Reset Password" class="btn btn-primary ml-auto" />
            </div>
        }
    }
</div>


  public class ResetPasswordViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "User Id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "User Name")]
        public string UserName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm password")]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
        public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
    }


[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    var user = _userManager.FindById(model.Id);

    IdentityResult result = null;

    if (user != null)
    {
        string code = await _userManager.GeneratePasswordResetTokenAsync(user.Id);

        result = await _userManager.ResetPasswordAsync(user.Id, code, model.Password);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ResetPasswordConfirmation", "Account", model);
        }
    }

    // return errors
    var s = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    //
    foreach (var e in result.Errors)
    {
        if (s.Length > 0)
        {
            s.Append(", ");
        }

        s.Append(e);
    }

    ViewBag.Error = s.ToString();

    return View();
}
```

Comment: AS I'm new to this, I'm not sure I understand what it is you've done. In the view, I see you have x, m, and model. How did you get the 3? Steep learning curve this is :) I'm doing an MVC course online but you can't really ask it questions, so you hunt around first, try things. If you can't get any further I come here and ask.

Comment: The code within the brackets of a HiddenFor, EditorFor (and so on) assume you are referencing the model so it doesn't matter what you name them (try hovering over them in the designer and you'll see it points to the model. Therefore, a=>a.SomeField and b=>b.SomeField create the same thing, a Lambda Expression with the same result.