# Asp.Net MVC Identity Reset Password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Reset Password by Admin - Without Email Link Only Admin can Reset Password, I get this code from [MVC Admin reset of User Password](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50255269/mvc-admin-reset-of-user-password) but in my project, I get an error on the line

```
await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);
```

Code:

```
    //
    // POST: /Account/ResetPassword
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ResetPassword(ResetPasswordViewModel model)
    {
        ApplicationDbContext context = new ApplicationDbContext();
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(context);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser> (store);

        string userId = model.Id;
        string newPassword = model.NewPassword;

        string hashedNewPassword = UserManager.PasswordHasher.HashPassword(newPassword);

        ApplicationUser cUser = await store.FindByIdAsync(userId);

        await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);
        await store.UpdateAsync(cUser);

        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kdbiI.png)

[View code of reset pass word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QEeyF.png)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Martheen When I type the new Password and Submit it the error
await store.SetPasswordHashAsync(cUser, hashedNewPassword);

Comment: That's the line where the error pops up, but what is the actual error? It would say something like exception, null, invalid etc

Comment: @Martheen 
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: user that is the error

Comment: [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult ResetPassword(string id)
        {
            return View(new ResetPasswordViewModel() { Id = id });
        }  I have this to get the Id of users

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: after seeing the view, the thing you can do is check if the view is actually getting an ID. Check the controller for the [get] action if it gives an id, one thing I do to check that is to temporarily change:

```
@Html.HiddenFor()
```

to

```
@Html.TextBoxFor()
```

then do a refresh.

You can also check the value of id in the breakpoint window if you are on debugging mode